# Debug ClassCastException

Tags: java, classloader

I run into a `ClassCastException`:

`Cannot cast my.package.classA to my.package.classA.`

Note that the (canonical) class (name) is the same.

I understand this should be related to different class loaders and/or loading the class from different jars.
The project is built using Maven.
Can I debug somehow which classloader was used in each case and from which jar the classes have been loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a breakpoint for `ClassCastException`.
For IntelliJ, this looks something like this:

[image: IntelliJ breakpoint]

Once the exception is caught, navigate in the debugger call hierarchy until you find the line where the cast should happen and you have a reference to both classes.

For example:

[image]

Now, you can inspect both classes (in my case `typeClass` and `instanceClass`). The class holds a reference to it's class loader.

In my case, it's `ModuleClassLoader for Module "my.ear" from Service Module Loader`
and
`ModuleClassLoader for Module "my-web-app.war" from Service Module Loader`

[image]

As you can see, one class is coming from the ear, the other one from the war.

**Change the dependency to `provided` in the web-app `pom.xml`, that should solve the problem.**

Note that the war file will not run anymore outside of the ear, if you need both scenarios, use a [Maven profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947096/maven-profiles-in-pom).